# Questions related to Christians and Jews of Hijaz

Tags: history

Did Hijaz have many Jews (Besides Madinah) and Christians? Also did they have acces to the Bible or was the Christianity and Judaism they practiced different of the Judaism and Christianity other non-Hijazis practiced?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How does a question whcih is more about Christian and Jewish belief fit to a Q&A site about Islam?

Answer (score 0):

As to my information, many Jews left Judea after the defeat in 71 CE and settled outside the Roman empire, partly in Arabia. Most settled either in the north (today southern Iraq and Kuwait) or in the south (Jemen). The Jewish community was probably the majority population in Medina.

The differences in Judaism over the word in this time was not very pronounced; Rabbinic Judaism (observing teachings in the Talmud) was followed both in Europe and in Middle-East.

Christian sects fled from the Roman empire where Christianity had become the statley religion in the 4th century CE, and Christians that did not want to follow the orthodox/catholic trinity doctrine were excluded or banned. They went to Persia, Arabia or southern Egypt. Now, these sects were not homogeneous

- The Arian/Nestorian Church of the East which upheld a Christology (Subordinarism) that is more complicated but quite close to the Quranic Christology. They formed probably the majority of Christians in Arabia.
- The Jacobite Monophysites who taught right the opposite, that Jesus and God were one.
- Rests of Gnostic groups (who added many own teachings that were rather based on Greek philosophy, teaching that Jesus was God, only having an appearant body) mainly went into Persia or further east, only some may have come to Arabia. We see little traces where those  are actively refuted in the Quran or in Hadith, from what we may conclude that they were not present in Hijaz.

Apart from those, the Orthodox Church was also present in Arabia.

It is not reported that Mekka or Medina had any imortant Christian community but Christians had settled in this area, and some of the Prophets companions had been (most probably Nestorian) Christians.